How to programmatically update and save passwords in Airflow connections
We would like to be able to programmatically update password values of Airflow Connections - I know there is a set_password() function in the Connection class, but it only changes the password in memory (i.e., it does not actually write the new value to the database).
Does anyone know how to make the changed password persist? (Is there, for instance, a connection manager class that I don't know about somewhere in the Airflow code base that knows how to do this?)

If your target to update Connection into the DB, then I would recommend to use Airflow REST API, direct save objects into the the DB could be changed in the future or even disabled.
